# Is there a way to pass back 2 different data types from a method in java?

Tags: java, arrays, methods, return

I am trying to populate an empty array in the first column with ordered numbers and write this back. This works, but I need the row location passed back too for reference in another method.

```
// Generate a customer/order number.
public static String[][] gen_cust_number(String[][] cust_order, int order_location)
{
    for(int row = 0; row < cust_order.length; row++)
    {
        if (cust_order[row][0] == null)
        {
            cust_order[row][0] = Integer.toString(row + 1000);  
            order_location = row;
            Gen.p("\n\n\tYour order number is : " + cust_order[row][0]);
            break;
        }
    }
    return cust_order;
}
```

I'm not very familiar with working with objects, pairs, and whatnot as I am still learning but have done some searching on it and am stumped in understanding how to do it.

Comment: In the future, if you ever need to return more than one value from a method, simply create a Class (private or public depending on access requirements).  Then just populate the class appropriately and return the instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure with what you're trying to achieve, but by reading the code I think what `get_cust_number` should do is

- Generate new order to the very first empty order list.
- Return the new order list and its index.

If this is right, **you don't have to pass the `String[][]`** back because the reference of this instance is what the caller side already know as it's passed in the parameters.

You can also remove the `order_location` param as it's never read inside the method.

So what you can do to make it work is to

1. Remove the `order_location` from params.
2. Return the index of added order instead of the array itself.

This results in the following code.

```java
// Generate a customer/order number.
public static int gen_cust_number(String[][] cust_order)
{
    for(int row = 0; row < cust_order.length; row++)
    {
        if (cust_order[row][0] == null)
        {
            cust_order[row][0] = Integer.toString(row + 1000);  
            Gen.p("\n\n\tYour order number is : " + cust_order[row][0]);
            return row;
        }
    }
    // cust_order is full
    return -1;
}
```

In the calling side, you can do the following:

```java
String[][] cust_order = /* Some orders according to your logic. */;
int cust_order_count = /* Number of the orders generated. */;

// Generate the order and this will be the new number of orders.
cust_order_count = gen_cust_number(cust_order);
```

Comment: Thankyou for the help Hyun I Kim, that solved the problem for me and was able to get the desired result.   I don't know how I didn't see that after all the looking I've been doing.  Again, many thanks.